# How do I use a date job parameter in Grails spring batch & SQL?

Tags: grails, spring-batch

I want to execute a query using 2 date job parameters that use late binding with Spring Batch.

```
JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder()
builder.addDate("until", until);
builder.addDate("start", start);
JobExecution exec = jobLauncher.run(myJob, builder.toJobParameters())
```

My beans / job definition:

```
myReader(JdbcPagingItemReader) { bean ->
    bean.scope = 'step'
    bean.autowire = 'byName'
    dataSource = ref('dataSource')
    queryProvider = ref('sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean')
    parameterValues = [
            start: "#{jobParameters['start']}",
            until: "#{jobParameters['until']}"
    ]
    pageSize = '10'
    rowMapper = ref('myRowMapper') // not shown here
}


sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean(SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean) { bean ->
    bean.autowire = 'byName'
    bean.scope = 'step'
    dataSource = ref('dataSource')
    selectClause = 'some_timestamp, column2'
    fromClause = 'some_table'
    whereClause = 'some_timestamp >= cast(:start as timestamp) AND some_timestamp < cast(:until as timestamp)'
    sortKey = 'some_timestamp'
}
```

I'm getting all sorts of errors, depending on how I cast the timestamps etc, such as (for the code above):

> step.AbstractStep Encountered an error executing step myStep in job
>   myJob org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT some_timestamp, column2 FROM
>   some_table WHERE some_timestamp >= cast(? as timestamp) AND
>   some_timestamp < cast(? as timestamp) ORDER BY some_timestamp ASC
>   LIMIT 10]; ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp:
>   "#{jobParameters['start']}"; nested exception is
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for
>   type timestamp: "#{jobParameters['start']}"nested exception is
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for
>   type timestamp: "#{jobParameters['start']}"

How do I access the timestamps for my query please?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I used [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991034/sqlpagingqueryproviderfactorybean-to-support-in-clause) as a clue and didn't bother with passing a parameter to the `SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean` and simply used the late binding here instead.

```
// within myReader, no need for parameters
// parameterValues = [
//        start: "#{jobParameters['start']}",
//        until: "#{jobParameters['until']}"
// ]


// within sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean
whereClause = "some_timestamp >= '#{jobParameters[\'start\']}'::timestamptz AND some_timestamp < '#{jobParameters[\'until\']}'::timestamptz"
```